# How can I stop my future builders to reload when I switch back to the tab again? - Flutter/dart

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am using a bottom navigation bar and every tab has a future builder and every time I switch to the next tab and switch back to the old one it reloads back

```dart
class LandingPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LandingPageState createState() => _LandingPageState();
}

class _LandingPageState extends State<LandingPage> {
  int _selectedIndex = 1;

  static List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    //Home
    HomePage(),

    //Search
    PostGridScreen(),

    //Favourites
    Text(
      'Index 1: Favourites',
    ),

    //Post
    AddPost(),

    //Index 4: Profile
    Profile(),
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          //Home
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.pets),
            label: 'Shop',
          ),

          //Search
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.search),
            label: 'Search',
          ),

          //Favourites
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
            label: 'Favourites',
          ),

          //Post
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add_box),
            label: 'Post',
          ),

          //Profile
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person),
            label: 'Profile',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.blue,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.black,
        selectedFontSize: 14,
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In the PostGridScreen() when I tap on a grid it gets me on the detail page and when I come back to the grid screen the data doesn't reload, but when I switch the tabs of my bottom navigation bar the data reloads and the future builders reload. Till now I have tried everything and I don't know what to do. Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin-mixin.html) and overriding the `wantKeepAlive` to return `true`, also adding the `super.build(context)` at the beginning of `build` method. This way, the state is persisted when navigating between tabs.

I have only used this with `PageView.builder()` and not your way (swapping child inside the Center widget based on tab index), so you just need to try that out, it may or may not work.